# Multiple jQuery Ajax calls in a Backbone App mixes data up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I work on a Backbone app with a collection for data sources. Whenever a new data source is added, its model is added to the collection, and a jQuery Ajax call is made for it like this:

```
fetch: function() {
        var model = this,
            url = model.get("url");

        function testCallback(parObj) {
            return function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert("test - "+parObj.url+" : "+data.sourceurl);
            }
        }

        $.ajax({
            url:        url,
            type:       "GET",
            dataType:   "jsonp",
            jsonpCallback:  "data",
            success:    testCallback({ model: model, url: url })
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            alert("done - "+model.get("url")+" : "+data.sourceurl);
        });
}
```

The fetch() is called in rapid succession, and debugging it I can see everything is ok when I initiate the Ajax request.

Everything works great if I only add two data sources.

But both the done() and testCallBack() functions mixes up the data when I have three requests running simultaneously on three different domains (same happens in both Chrome and Safari).

For instance:

- URL 1 gets the data from URL 1.
- URL 2 gets the data from URL 3.
- URL 3 gets the data from URL 2.

Am I doing something wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're setting the `jsonpCallback` parameter to the same thing for each request. Just remove that line entirely as jQuery will automatically create unique ones for you.

Comment: Thanks! So obvious it's embarrassing. In this instance I will have to make a queue as the data sources are hardcoded documents I don't control.